# jQuery form deserialization for all inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, deserialization

I've been using a simple each function for deserializing a form:

```
  data = { key : val, ... };
  form = $('#formId');
  $.each(data, function(val,i) {
    form.find('*[name="' + val + '"]').val(data[val]);
  });
```

but I can't seem to get it to work for non-standard form elements (i.e. radio buttons/checkboxes).  I've been playing with different examples for a few hours and can't get it to work. Anyone know an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Have you looked into datalink plugin (http://api.jquery.com/link/)?

Comment: looking for a non-plugin solution, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/BkaW3/1/)

html:

```
<form id="formId">
    a: <input name="a" /><br />
    b: <input name="b" /><br />
    c: <input type="checkbox" name="c" /><br />
    d: <select name="d"><option value="d1">d1</option><option value="d2">d2</option></select><br />
    e: <input type="radio" value="1" name="e" /><br />
    e: <input type="radio" value="2" name="e" /><br />
    e: <input type="radio" value="3" name="e" /><br />
    f: <input type="checkbox" name="f" /><br />
</form>
```

js:

```
var 
    data = { a: "value for a", b: "value for b", c: false, d:"d2", e: "2", f:true },
   form = $('#formId');

   $.each(data, function(i, el) {

      var 
          fel = form.find('*[name="' + i + '"]'),
          type = "", tag = "";

       if (fel.length > 0) {

           tag = fel[0].tagName.toLowerCase();

           if (tag == "select" || tag == "textarea") { //...
              $(fel).val(el);
           }
           else if (tag == "input") {
              type = $(fel[0]).attr("type");
               if (type == "text" || type == "password" || type == "hidden") {
                  fel.val(el);
               } 
               else if (type == "checkbox") {
                  if (el)  
                     fel.attr("checked", "checked"); 
               }
               else if (type == "radio") {
                   fel.filter('[value="'+el+'"]').attr("checked", "checked"); 
               }
           }
       }
   })
```

Comment: this code doesn't loop through multiple elements of the same name but it's close enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a plug-in like [this](http://www.reach1to1.com/sandbox/jquery/testform.html) can help.

```
$('#form-id').deserialize([{'name':'firstname','value':'John'},{'name':'lastname','value':'Resig'}]);
```

Looks like it hasn't been updated in a couple of years.

Comment: really looking for a non-plugin solution, but I'll check it out.  thanks!